# what is the correct way to import a mongoose schema model and not just the objectid into another schema

Tags: mongoose-schema

Purpose: CRM ticketing system
It will be having 3 main schemas- CLIENT, EMPLOYEE and ADMIN interacting with the TICKET Schema.

all 3 main schemas would be having  a userSchema which would contain all the common details inside like name, email, password, address, etc.

Is it possible to import userSchema defined inside one file to be imported into another like inside clientSchema.

Currently the only way i can do so is by defining the schema object in same file before defining the main schema obj

eg. using nameSchema to

```
    const reqString = {
    type: String,
    required: true,
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: reqString,
})
```

trying any other method like if making reqString a new mongoose.schema and trying to import it into another file makes the require: true validation fail

eg. if i do something like

```
const { nameSchema } = require("./basemodel");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: nameSchema,
})
```

and basemodel.js is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

module.exports = { nameSchema }
```

Or if im doing like

```
name: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types,
    ref: "Name",
},
```

why am i still able to create a user without a name with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use 3 different schemas, so your data will not be messed up in db and frontend page.

Comment: i have edited the question to be slightly more clear, and i would like to reuse the schemas if possible,